# most efficent way to parse XML With NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsxmlparser

I am trying to figure out the best approach to parsing large datasets of xml with the xmlparser delegate.. (basically what the heck do i put the data into?)

the xml data will look like this.

```
<Rows>
<Row ID="76" MANF="JARD" ISMANUF="F" ISSER="F"/>
<Row ID="38" MANF ="SANBIN" ISMANUF ="F" ISSER ="T"/>
<Rows>
```

I am looking for a high level responses so I can go away and do more research as their is obviously several  different ways of going about this.. I would like to know the best/most efficient to store the data coming back from NSXMLParser and also would like something that I will have the ability to cache...

Thus far I have been looking at NSMutabledictionarys however have heard this might not be sutible so I have now started to look at creating my own object.. but the data coming back from my parsing delegate is only compatible with strings.. so if i have a bool value I cannot put it into my object.. any help would be greatly appreciated as I am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: The [most efficient way to parse XML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) is not with `NSXMLParser`. I'd use [`TBXML`](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html).

Comment: hrmm.. intresting (i didnt even know their were different types other than JASON and NSXMLParser).. I think for now I will stick with NSXMLParser as I am still learning. I wanted to know more so whats the best way of storing the data coming in.. my own NSObject or NSDictionary etc..

Comment: `NSDictionary` is a better native type, particularly since you can save it straight to disk in the form of a `.plist` without too much hassle. Lookup is fairly quick for an `NSDictionary`, since there's no tree structure to search through compared to a bunch of `NSObjects` representing XML elements in an XML tree.

Comment: how would you assing NSDictionary values from an XML data set like the  one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented an efficient enough XML-to-`NSDictionary` parser. You can return it as an `NSMutableDictionary` if you want to. I don't currently have a github or anything up, so I'll post the code inline here. It makes use of the [`TBXML`](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) XML parsing library (no XPath support, and read-only parsing, but fairly efficient and high-level).

*EDIT:* I just realised, my parser was made to parse element names and text inside the elements, but not element **attributes**, which is how your XML dataset is laid out. Unfortunately, the below code won't parse the attributes. You've got a starting point though, you can change the code which uses `->firstChild` and `->nextSibling` to read attributes.

---

**XML.h**

```
@interface XML : NSObject

/**
 * Constructs an NSDictionary from the provided XML tree.
 *
 * Uses the default prefix of 'config'.
 */
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLTree:(TBXMLElement *)tree;

/**
 * Constructs an NSDictionary from the provided XML tree.
 *
 * The format of the dictionary keys is:
 * section/[subsection/.../]optionName
 */
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLTree:(TBXMLElement *)tree
                            withPrefix:(NSString *)keyPrefix;

/**
 * Iteratively parses configuration areas from the provided XML document.
 *
 * If an 'list' area is encountered, its immediate children are added to
 * the dictionary as a numbered list (i.e list/1/..., list/2/...).
 */
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromXML:(TBXML *)xmlDoc;

@end
```

---

**XML.m**

```
NSString *stripHTML(const char* xmlString);

NSString* stripHTML(const char* xmlString)
{
    return [[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:xmlString]
      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;"
      withString:@"&"]
     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#13;"
            withString:@""];
}

@implementation XML

@synthesize configDict;

#pragma mark - XML parsing

+ (NSDictionary *)itemisedDictionaryForXMLTree:(TBXMLElement *)tree
                                    withPrefix:(NSString *)keyPrefix
{
    NSMutableDictionary *returnValues =
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSUInteger itemNumber = 1;
    for (TBXMLElement *option = tree->firstChild;
         option != nil;
         option = option->nextSibling)
    {
        if(option->text == NULL)
            option->text = "";

        NSString *childPrefix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%u",
                                 keyPrefix, itemNumber++];
        [returnValues setObject:stripHTML(option->text)
                         forKey:childPrefix];

        [returnValues addEntriesFromDictionary:
         [self dictionaryForXMLTree:option withPrefix:childPrefix]];
    }

    return [returnValues autorelease];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLTree:(TBXMLElement *)tree
                            withPrefix:(NSString *)keyPrefix
{
    NSMutableDictionary *returnValues =
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (TBXMLElement *option = tree->firstChild;
         option != nil;
         option = option->nextSibling)
    {        
        if(option->text == NULL)
            option->text = "";

        NSString *childPrefix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%s",
                                 keyPrefix,
                                 option->name];
        [returnValues setObject:stripHTML(option->text)
                         forKey:childPrefix];

        [returnValues addEntriesFromDictionary:
         [self dictionaryForXMLTree:option withPrefix:childPrefix]];
    }

    return [returnValues autorelease];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLTree:(TBXMLElement *)tree
{
    return [self dictionaryForXMLTree:tree withPrefix:@"config"];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromXML:(TBXML *)xmlDoc
{
    NSMutableDictionary *config = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    TBXMLElement *rootElement = [xmlDoc rootXMLElement];
    if(rootElement != nil)
    {
        for(TBXMLElement *configArea = rootElement->firstChild;
            configArea != nil;
            configArea = configArea->nextSibling)
        {
            NSString *areaName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",
                                  configArea->name];
            if([areaName
                isEqualToString:@"list"]) // multiple children with the same name
            {
                [config addEntriesFromDictionary:
                 [self itemisedDictionaryForXMLTree:configArea
                                         withPrefix:areaName]];
            } else {
                [config addEntriesFromDictionary:
                 [self dictionaryForXMLTree:configArea
                                 withPrefix:areaName]];
            }
        }
    }

    [pool release];
    return [config autorelease];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)fetchConfig:(NSURL *)atURL
{
    TBXML *xmlDoc = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:atURL];
    return [XML dictionaryFromXML:xmlDoc];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)parseConfigFromXMLString:(NSString *)xmlString
{
    TBXML *xmlDoc = [TBXML tbxmlWithXMLString:xmlString];
    return [XML dictionaryFromXML:xmlDoc];
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks.. this will give me great insight into TBXML... Im going to have to study this over the next couple of days but I am extremely grateful for your help.. cheers.

Comment: Added an addendum at the top of my answer. You'll need to modify this code to fit your needs.

Comment: cool.. thats the most confusing part about it for me.. i have been so used to parsing just the elements. thanks for that.

Comment: TBXML should make it easier. It parses the attributes for you so all you need to do is add them from the TBXML structure to the dictionary in whatever way you like :)

Comment: [Here](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Extracting_attributes.html) is a link to how to do it using TBXML (I know, it's *really* simple, isn't it?)

Comment: :P lol indeed!! this is great stuff, thank you very much for your help! this is going to make things so much better.